# How does Android Framework process the option of 'don't keep activities'?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, activity-stack

I know how to handle "Don't keep activities" option in App. I can use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, etc.

In this question, I want to know how the **Android Framework** handles the option. eg.

1. When user switches the App to the background, we know the current Activity will be destroyed. But I don't know how the Framework to do this. I can't find the process in Framework. I need your help to provide some clues of the process in source code.
2. If only one Activity in you App, and you switch the App to the background, is the `ActivityStack` destroyed？When you switch the app from background to foreground, will the   `ActivityStack` be recreated? Can you provide some source code.

Thank you for your reading. Maybe you can write something. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the source code handy, so can't be sure, but I assume that it works as if you would set `android:noHistory="true"` on all activities.

The answer to your second question is that the single `Activity` would be destroyed, leaving the `ActivityStack` empty. When the user returns to the app, a new instance of the `Activity` would be created and initialized with the previously saved state of the `Activity`. The OS process may or may not be destroyed and recreated in this case, it depends how long the app was left in the background and how aggressive the implementation of the Android framework is (this behaviour is different, depending on device manufacturer and on the amount of resources the device has).

Comment: Thanks David. I try it. `android:noHistory="true"` is different from `don't keep acitivites`.
If I have A,B,C Activities, B and C are set `android:noHistory="true"`. The route is A -> B -> C. In C, I press the BACK key then I back to A, not B. B is destroyed already, and not is recreated. But `don't keep acitivites` will make B to be recreated.

Comment: So, it results to other question. In normal situation, an Activity will be removed from the ActivityStack when it is destroyed. But in `don't keep acitivites` situation, how does the **Android Framework** keep the Activity in ActivityStack even though it is destroyed? Because, you can back to the pervious Activity when you press BACK key.

Comment: Android remembers the activities in the `ActivityStack`. In normal operation if you have 12 activities in the activity stack and your task goes to the background and Android kills off the OS process, when the user returns to the app, Android creates a new OS process and launches a new instance of the `Activity` that **was on the top of the stack**. If the user then presses BACK, Android will create a new instance of the `Activity` that was **previously on top of the stack**, and if the user continues to press BACK, Android will create new instances of all the other activities, one at a time.

Comment: And yes, it makes sense that **don't keep Activities** doesn't match exactly the behaviour of `android:noHistory="true"`.  Sorry about that. The thing is that **don't keep Activities** is a debugging aid, used to help you test your app's behaviour when Android kills off the activities under certain situations. But I would need to look at the code to see exactly how it works.